# Table is not creating in MySQL in SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have created a spring boot project in eclipse. Every setup was fine but the annotation I used in POJO class is not creating table in database. And the 'index.jsp' also not working when ran this project as spring boot app.

Initially I tried in H2 database. In that I can able to connect to H2 console but the table is not created I don't know why. Then I tried in MySql same result but now I couldn't even view "index.jsp" from localhost/8080. Someone guide me I know I'm noob in this.

User.Java

```
package com.shriram.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column (name = "ID")
  private int id;
  @Column (name = "NAME")
  private String name;
  
  
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  

}
```

UserDAO.java

```
package com.shriram.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.shriram.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserDAO extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{

}
```

UserController.java

```
package com.shriram.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.shriram.dao.UserDAO;
import com.shriram.model.User;

@Controller
public class UserController {
  
  @Autowired
  UserDAO userdao;
  
  @RequestMapping("index")
  public String user()
  {
    return "index.jsp";
  }
  
  @RequestMapping("addUser")
  public String user(User user)
  {
    userdao.save(user);
    return "index.jsp";
  }

}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="addUser">

        Enter ID <input type="text" name="id"></input><br> 
        Enter Name <input type="text" name="name"></input>
            
            <button type="submit"> SUBMIT </button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
server.port=9090
```

Comment: Go ahead and show us error logs please.

Comment: I recommend you not using table name "user". It is reserved for mysql

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SuchandraT i'm getting this error after I submit the data in index.jsp Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Tue May 02 01:59:46 IST 2023 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Comment: @Asgar I tried with the different name but it is not updating anything in db

Comment: I was not mentioning the solution @Shriram, It was a suggestion "not to use reserved keywords"

Answer (score -1):

Remove @Table annotation . @Entity is enough if database doest have table.

Comment: I tried at first itself that doesn't helped me.